# Ubuntu One and missing folders from Thunderbird

Tags: ubuntu-one, thunderbird

I have Thunderbird 11 installed on Ubuntu 11.4

I copied the mail folder (plus subfolders) to the Ubuntu One sync folder, and now when opening Thunderbird all my local folders are missing.

The folders are still physically on my hard drive in the correct place and the message store setting is correct but the folders aren't showing.

What's gone wrong?

Thanks

Sam

Comment: Sorry no answer from me, but you are not alone. I have had exactly the same issues. Fortunately my mail is collected using IMAP so I could easily reconfigure again, but I spent a few weeks on this one issue and in the end I abandoned using Ubuntu One for Thunderbird mail. I hope someone does have the answer.

Comment: If you "copied" them they would still be there where they belong. Perhaps you "moved" or "cut" them from Thunderbird? If U1 has them, just copy them back.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!